# Query from Azure Comos DB and save to Azure Table Storage using Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I want to save C._ts+C.ttl as **one entity** in my Azure Table Storage. I do the following query in my Copy Activity:

```
"typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
            "query": {
                "value": "@concat('SELECT (C.ts+C.ttl) FROM C WHERE (C.ttl+C._ts)<= ', string(pipeline().parameters.bufferdays))",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "nestingSeparator": "."
        },
```

I **dont** want to copy all the fields from my source i.e. CosmosDB to my sink i.e. Table Storage. I just want to store the result of this query as **one value**. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you hitting any problem with your current settings? It looks good.

Comment: No, it just saves null in all the columns in my table storage. How do I specify which column(in Azure Table Storage) should the result of this query from source get saved to?

Comment: Could you share the activity run ID?

Comment: And if you want to store the result to a specified column, you could use column mapping to specify the mapping rules.

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: Hi, any updates now ?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, I presume the `null` value you queried because of that the collection level `ttl` affects each document , but will not generate `ttl` property within document.

So when you execute `SELECT c.ttl,c._ts FROM c` , just get below result.

[image]

Document level `ttl` is not defined, just follow collection level `ttl`.

[image]

You need to bulk add ttl property into per document so that you could transfer `_ts+ttl` caculator results.

Your Copy Activity settings looks good , just add an alias in SQL, or set the name of the field via column mapping.

Hope it helps you.